# Function Template specialisation pass value from struct constructor to a helper struct's constructor

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

This could be an easy answer to what I am facing, but I have tried my best the search previous posts, but none directly maps to what I need. The code below has a master (`bmGsNoSuff`) and slave (`bmGsNoSuffHelper`) . The Idea is, I want to pass the variable `j` from `bmGsNoSuff` such that it gets used by the inner called struct `bmGsNoSuffHelper` . It turns out, I cannot do this so long as `j` has been declared as a parameter of `bmGsNoSuff`'s constructor. The compiler alarms : `error: ‘j’ cannot appear in a constant-expression bmGsNoSuffHelper<I,j>()(BmGs, suff, i  );`

What could be the way out of this? How can I pass `j` from the master to the helper?

```
 template<typename I , int j>
    struct bmGsNoSuffHelper
    {
            void operator () ( I BmGs[], I suff[] ,int i )
            {
               if ( j < size - 1 -i ){
                   if(BmGs[j]==size){
                      BmGs[j]=size-1-i;
                    }
                    bmGsNoSuffHelper<I,j+1>()(BmGs, suff, i  ); // InitialiseBmGs<I,i+1> () ( BmGs);
                }
            }
    };
    template<typename I>
    struct bmGsNoSuffHelper<I, size>
    {
           void operator () (I BmGs[], I suff[], int i  )   {}
    };


    //BmGsNoSuff
    template<typename I , int i>
    struct bmGsNoSuff
    {
            void operator () ( I BmGs[], I suff[], int j )
            {
               if ( i >=-1 ){
                   if((i==-1) || ( suff[i] == i+1)){
                          bmGsNoSuffHelper<I,j>()(BmGs, suff, i  );
                    }
                    bmGsNoSuff<I,i-1>()( BmGs, suff, j + 1  );  
                }
            }
    };
    template<typename I>
    struct bmGsNoSuff<I, -2>
    {
           void operator () (I BmGs[], I suff[] , int j)   {}
    };
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but shouldn't `bmGsNoSuffHelper` at least be a template? You specialize it later on, and I don't see where this `j` comes from. Perhaps from the missing template declaration?

Comment: Also, in the non-specialized `bmGsNoSuff`, you're using the runtime parameter `j` to instantiate the template `bmGsNoSuffHelper<I, j>`.

Comment: @JorenHeit, I had left the template declaration by mistatke , thanks.

Comment: The idea is to have a way to send ` j`  from ` bmGsNoSuff` to `bmGsNoSuffHelper` so the it can do recursive computations bases on the newly passed value.

Comment: You can only do that if `j` itself is a constant expression, e.g. a template parameter rather than a function parameter.